# Compare a string in if()

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to compare a string in an if(string = ""), but it's apparently not the same

the string is "thisColor", it is defined by the content of a file.
I tried using Debug.Log(thisColor), the result is "rouge" but it's not recognized in if(thisColor == "rouge"). I also tried switch(thisColor) then case()...

Maybe it's the encoding..?

Here is the code snippet:

```
        thisColor = "";

        pixelSetup = GameObject.Find("Pixel" + setupPixelNumber.ToString());

        setupPixelNumber += 1;

        if (File.Exists("C:/PekmiIndustries/MVPlace/Pixel" + pixell + ".txt"))
        {
            thisColor = File.ReadAllText("C:/PekmiIndustries/MVPlace/Pixel" + pixell + ".txt");
        }
        else
        {
            File.Create("C:/PekmiIndustries/MVPlace/Pixel" + pixell + ".txt").Dispose();
        }

        string[] retourSuppr = new string[] { "\n" };
        foreach(var c in retourSuppr)
        {
            thisColor = thisColor.Replace(c, string.Empty);
        }
        pixell = pixelSetup;

        pixell.GetComponent<Renderer>().enabled = true;

        Debug.Log("thisColor = |" + thisColor + "|");


        if (thisColor != "")
        {
            Debug.Log(thisColor);
            if (thisColor == "rouge")
            {
                Debug.Log("done.");
                pixell.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = new Color(255f / 255f, 0, 0, 1);
                thisColor = "";
            }
            else if (thisColor == "orangeF")
            {
                pixell.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = new Color(255f / 255f, 70f / 255f, 0 / 255f, 1);
                thisColor = "";
            }
            else if (thisColor == "orange")
            {
                pixell.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = new Color(255f / 255f, 128f / 255f, 0 / 255f, 1);
                thisColor = "";
            }
            
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("Passed");
            }
```

thanks          :)

Comment: Are you sure you have no space or anything at the end of your textfile ?

Comment: Or it’s reading a line feed

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint in your line and examine the actual contents of `thisColor`? Or does this issue only occur in production?

Comment: I'm sure that there is not space or anything else

Comment: I tried for the line feed with that :
string[] retourSuppr = new string[] { "\n" };
            foreach(var c in retourSuppr)
            {
                thisColor = thisColor.Replace(c, string.Empty);
            }

I think it replace \n by nothing?
In the debug.log, there is no line feed

Comment: What's the console log for the line `Debug.Log("thisColor = |" + thisColor + "|");`?

Comment: thisColor = |rouge|

Comment: @Pekmi try if (thisColor.startsWith("rouge")), if it goes through, it means you have something more than "rouge" in your textfile

Comment: but when I paste it, it appear :
thisColor = |rouge
|

so there is a line feed?

Comment: I don't understand why there was nothing else than "rouge" in the console, but it's okay x')

Comment: @Pekmi this is because of the encoding used by Unity's console. It does not show that type of characters because it interprets it. In fact, real answer might be this `File.ReadAllText("yourTextFile.txt", ,Encoding.Unicode);` with this you might be able to strip these unwanted chars from the textfile and use '==' instead of 'startsWidth'

Comment: ok that was interesting
thanks again :)

Comment: I'll add the answer for every one else if it works

Comment: It works you can add it

Answer (score 1):

This is because your file is encoded with something different than UTF-8, which is the default reading method used by `ReadAllText`

As said in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8591725/2564406) you can tell `ReadAllText` to use unicode instead.

```
File.ReadAllText("yourTextFile.txt", Encoding.Unicode);
```

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure you "thisColor = File.ReadAllText("C:/PekmiIndustries/MVPlace/Pixel" + pixell + ".txt");" result,but i think the result contains space bar，so you can try this:

thisColor=thisColor.Replace(" ","")

Comment: it didn't change anything, thanks anyway

the lines 
string[] retourSuppr = new string[] { "\n" };
        foreach(var c in retourSuppr)
        {
            thisColor = thisColor.Replace(c, string.Empty);
        }

don't do the same?

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that "rouge" is among the words, just use `Contains`:

```
if (thisColor.Contains("rouge"))
{
   // do something
}
```